# WebForms - How to remove page references

Tags: asp.net, webforms

If you had to remove a page from a WebForms project, what is the best way to find out if that page is referred to in other pages?(ex: links).

Would a simple but long running search in the entire solution for that page's name suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably Ctrl + f and type the name of the page. Instead of just search current document, you can search the current project or the entire solution. I'm not too sure of any other way.

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm searching it, but it's a big project, and I have to delete several pages and it takes rather a long time. I was hoping there wss a better way.

Comment: I was an idiot and was using the QuickFind instead of FindInFiles and had to keep doing a 'find next' :| Now it's a lot easier.